# How is Low-Quality post decided by the system?

Tags: support

I have always wondered how a low quality post is decided by the system. Is this even decided by the system or is it a manual process?

What qualities should a post contain so that it does not become a **Low-Qualtiy-Post**?

Comment: It is definitely decided by the system and some are even flagged for mods.  This typically has to do with character count I believe.  I will have to dig something up for it.

Comment: answer: it's magic

Comment: @DForck42 haha...nice. But magics are even discovered and explained by humans. So it should not get away unexplained too! ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Low quality posts are detected through a combination of length, formatting, use of certain keywords, and a few bad habits that correlate to poor quality.

I don't believe the algorithm has been thoroughly documented anywhere (most likely to prevent minimum-effort posts, gaming, and workarounds), but there was a discussion to explore the issues and techniques before it was implemented:

[**Heuristics for detecting a bad answer**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72523/heuristics-for-detecting-a-bad-answer)

That was an early discussion, and not all of the techniques discussed made it into the current system.

Comment: Thank you for the piece of info @robert cartaino :)